# limpar campos póstumos

Tags: jquery

`jQuery`:

```
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $("#idPastor").on("change", function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "_scripts/_php/_validacoes/buscarDadosRedes.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                  idPastor: $("#idPastor").val()
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#imgCarregando").css('display','block');
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#imgCarregando").css('display','none');
                $('#idRede').find('option').remove();

                if (result == null){
                    $("#idRede").append("<option value=>Sem Redes</option>");
                } else {
                    $("#idRede").append("<option value=>Escolha a Rede</option>");
                    result.forEach(function(option){
                        $("#idRede").append("<option value=" + option["idRede"] + ">" + option["nome"] + "</option>")
                    });
                }
            }

        });

    });


    $("#idRede").on("change", function () {                   

        $.ajax({
            url: "_scripts/_php/_validacoes/buscarDadosRegioes.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                  idRede: $("#idRede").val()
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#imgCarregando").css('display','block');
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#imgCarregando").css('display','none');
                $('#idRegiao').find('option').remove();
                if (result == null){
                    $("#idRegiao").append("<option value=>Sem Regiões</option>");
                } else {
                    $("#idRegiao").append("<option value=>Escolha a Região</option>");                      
                    result.forEach(function(option){
                        $("#idRegiao").append("<option value=" + option["idRegiao"] + ">" + option["nome"] + "</option>")
                    });
                }
            }

        });

    });


    $("#idRegiao").on("change", function () {                       


        $.ajax({
            url: "_scripts/_php/_validacoes/buscarDadosAreas.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                  idRegiao: $("#idRegiao").val()
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#imgCarregando").css('display','block');
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#imgCarregando").css('display','none');      
                $('#idArea').find('option').remove();           
                if (result == null){    
                    $("#idArea").append("<option value=>Sem Áreas</option>");
                } else {            
                    $("#idArea").append("<option value=>Escolha a Área</option>");  
                    result.forEach(function(option){
                        $("#idArea").append("<option value=" + option["idArea"] + ">" + option["nome"] + "</option>")
                    });
                }
            }

        });

    });


    $("#idArea").on("change", function () {                 


        $.ajax({
            url: "_scripts/_php/_validacoes/buscarDadosSetores.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                  idArea: $("#idArea").val()
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#imgCarregando").css('display','block');
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#imgCarregando").css('display','none');
                $('#idSetor').find('option').remove();                      
                if (result == null){
                    $("#idSetor").append("<option value=>Sem Setores</option>");
                } else {
                    $("#idSetor").append("<option value=>Escolha a Setor</option>");        
                    result.forEach(function(option){
                        $("#idSetor").append("<option value=" + option["idSetor"] + ">" + option["nome"] + "</option>")
                    });
                }
            }

        });

    });


    $("#idSetor").on("change", function () {                        


        $.ajax({
            url: "_scripts/_php/_validacoes/buscarDadosCelulas.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                  idSetor: $("#idSetor").val()
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#imgCarregando").css('display','block');
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#imgCarregando").css('display','none');
                $('#idCelula').find('option').remove();     
                if (result == null){
                    $("#idCelula").append("<option value=>Sem Celulas</option>");
                } else {
                    $("#idCelula").append("<option value=>Escolha a Célula</option>");      
                    result.forEach(function(option){
                        $("#idCelula").append("<option value=" + option["idCelula"] + ">" + option["nome"] + "</option>")
                    });
                }
            }

        });

    });


});
```

Esse script, faz a população via `$.ajax` do `jQuery` de combos no form.
Tudo funciona bem.

Mas considere o o `form` abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagine o que o usuário preencheu todos os campos e de repente resolve tocar a opção do select de Redes como está na figura.

Porém, a opção `Rede 2` NÃO possui Regiões Cadastradas ainda.
No entanto, note que todos os campos abaixo estão preenchidos e isso não negaria um possível submit do form com dados errados?

Ainda,  imagine a situação onde a opção `Rede 2` POSSUI outas Regiões Cadastradas o que comprometeria a escolha dos `selects` que seguem

como contornar esse problema?

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o ideal é você definir quais campos são obrigatórios e quais são campos "relacionados".

Quando houver uma relação entre campos você precisa ter a definição da ordem/hierarquia em que eles são preenchidos.

Sempre deixe nos combos uma opção em branco, para permitir a "limpeza" dos campos.

A partir dessas premissas, sempre que houver mudanças em campos relacionados que sejam  "pais" você precisa limpar o valor selecionado dos campos "filhos" dele (que naturalmente, são os campos seguintes a serem preenchidos).

Se os campos filhos forem obrigatórios, ao tentar submeter o formulário a validação não irá deixar.